# How do I connect Apache2 and PHP5?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, php5, lamp

I'm trying to install the LAMP stack on a server running Ubuntu 10.10.

Whenever I browser to a PHP file on the server, my browser will download it as a file named "download" (with no extension). I have php5 installed, I have libapache2-mod-php5, I have purged and reinstalled the packages many times, and nothing has helped.

What can I do? I can provide config files, system info, etc. if necessary.

Comment: I'm guessing you already tried the dumb things?

Comment: Yes, I have already.

Comment: @Ignacio_Vazquez-Abrams - "I'm guessing you already tried the dumb things?" - ... but everyone has a different definition of what is and isn't dumb ...

Answer (score 1):

First, consider removing any PHP application files under the web root (it's possible, though not likely, that the "download" thing is the intended action...)

A few troubleshooting steps:

1. `wget -S localhost` - What do your Server headers indicate?
2. `sudo dpkg --list | grep php` - Which PHP packages are installed?
3. `echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" >
   /var/www/index.php` - Create a
   phpinfo call and test (**restart and test** if desired)
4. `sudo a2enmod php5` - should print "Module php5 already enabled" (**restart and test** if desired)
5. `sudo grep "mods-enabled" /etc/apache2/*` should print: `apache2.conf:Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load` and `apache2.conf:Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf` (if not, add these directives at the end of your apache2.conf file, then **restart and test**)
6. `sudo cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf` should include the line `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3` - if this directive is wrapped in an IfModule conditional, comment out the IfModule conditional for testing (**restart and test**)

Comment: Awesome troubleshooting list.